# Puppet: How to write a proper “condition and condition” statement?

Tags: puppet, ruby, scripting

I wrote a "Message of the day" Puppet module which affects all proxy servers in my company.
Within the template file, I have the following "if statement":

```
<% if @hostname !~ /^haproxy\d+/ and @hostname =~ /proxy\d+/ -%>
if [ "$(cat $LBMEMFILE)" = "0" ]; then
echo -e "\e[35m Membeship in LB:  Yes"
elif [ "$(cat $LBMEMFILE)" = "2" ]; then
echo -e "\e[35m Membeship in LB:    No $LISTMEMFILE"
fi
<% end -%>
```

It's meaning:

If hostname is proxy0-100 and not ^haproxy0-100 then add a line to the motd script.

But for some reason this statement doesn't work.

I also tried using "unless" but to no avail.

If I remove the statement after the "and" in the first line, it works like a charm.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass at /etc/puppet/environments/production/manifests/site.pp:1 on node haproxy02.company.com
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think you are using bash code in your template

Comment: This is a bash code wrapped in Ruby code.
As mentioned above, if I remove the second statement (the one after the `and`) then the statement works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem... there was an extra space in the `.yaml` file which caused the error.
Thanks for your help.